# Stop Streamlit Share

Tags: python, share, streamlit

I am trying to share an app with streamlit share. I have all documents in this [repository](https://github.com/iarevaloe/practica_OD_VD.git).
When I create a New App in share.streamlit I get this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h4pq.png) and It doesn't continue. Does anyone how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend rebooting the app if it doesn't finish loading. Otherwise, deleting it and re-deploying might be helpful. One possibility is that your dependencies exceed the memory limit of 1GB, so your app is getting stuck due to hitting the memory limit.